# InvalidArgumentError when training a seq2seq model

Tags: seq2seq

I'm trying to use sequence to sequence model on words but during training I keep getting invalid argument error. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me out.

Here's a sample code to reproduce the error I'm getting.

I'm using,
tensorflow 2.0.0, cudatoolkit 10.0.130, cudnn 7.6.4

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x = ['this is really good',
 'i am feeling better',
 'yesterday was a bad day',
 'today is better']

y = ['<sos> Ceci est vraiment bon <eos>',
     '<sos> je me sens mieux <eos>',
     '<sos> hier était une mauvaise journée <eos>',
     "<sos> aujourd'hui c`est mieux <eos>"]

x_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(np.hstack([i.split() for i in x])), range(1, 16)))
y_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(np.hstack([i.split() for i in y])), range(1, 18)))

MAX_LEN_X = 5
MAX_LEN_Y = 7

encoder_input = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_X), dtype='float32')

for i, j in enumerate(x):
    for k, l in enumerate(j.split()):
        encoder_input[i, k] = x_dict[l]

decoder_input = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_Y), dtype='float32')
decoder_output = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_Y, len(y_dict)+1), dtype='float32')

for i, j in enumerate(y):
    for k, l in enumerate(j.split()):
        decoder_input[i, k] = y_dict[l]
        if k > 0:
            decoder_output[i, k - 1, y_dict[l]] = 1.

latent_dim = 30
INPUT_VOCAB = len(x_dict)
TARGET_VOCAB = len(y_dict) + 1

# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
encoder_emb =  Embedding(INPUT_VOCAB, latent_dim, mask_zero=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_emb)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Decoder
decoder_inputs  = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(TARGET_VOCAB, latent_dim, mask_zero=True)
decoder_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(TARGET_VOCAB, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Here is the full traceback of the error I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f704c3b2a0b8> in <module>
      2            epochs=10,
      3            verbose=1,
----> 4            shuffle=True)

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    726         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    727         workers=workers,
--> 728         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    729 
    730   def evaluate(self,

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    455 
    456     tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()
--> 457     result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    458     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():
    459       self._call_counter.called_without_tracing()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    518         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    519         # stateless function.
--> 520         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    521     else:
    522       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1821     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1822     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1823     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1824 
   1825   @property

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  indices[3,0] = 14 is not in [0, 14)
     [[node model/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at /home/user83/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]
     [[loss/dense_loss/weighted_loss/broadcast_weights/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/else/_13/Assert/data_2/_92]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  indices[3,0] = 14 is not in [0, 14)
     [[node model/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at /home/user83/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_distributed_function_16237]

Function call stack:
distributed_function -> distributed_function
```

Comment: Can you post the line of code in which you got the error?

Comment: I'll update the post with full traceback. If you just run this sample code you'll also get that error

Comment: @thushv89 Have I done something wrong in my sequence to sequence model implementation? I tried to debut but I just can't understand why I'm receiving the error.

Comment: I figured out the error. Will post the answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So few mistakes in your code.

### Vocabulary sizes (Encoder and Decoder)

If you do a `print(x_dict)` you will see that your vocabularies start at 1 and go up to some value (let's say `n`). Now you set the `INPUT_VOCAB` as `len(x_dict)`. This leaves your `Embedding` layer lacking a row for the last word in your vocabulary. So whenever your model encounters that last words you get that `embedding_look_up` type error. So you need to set `INPUT_SIZE=len(x_dict)+1`

### Having two `None` in your output shapes

This is personally something I always try to avoid. It is okay to leave your batch dimension `None`. But having more than one `None` in your output shape is dangerous. For example TensorFlow/Keras sometimes does reshaping in layers. If you have more than one `None` you cannot recover the original shape of the Tensor (or probably not even allowed to perform reshaping). Either way, it is not the best practice. So I've set the sequence lengths in your `Input` shapes.

So after the changes your code looks like this.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Embedding
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

x = ['this is really good',
 'i am feeling better',
 'yesterday was a bad day',
 'today is better']

y = ['<sos> Ceci est vraiment bon <eos>',
     '<sos> je me sens mieux <eos>',
     '<sos> hier était une mauvaise journée <eos>',
     "<sos> aujourd'hui c`est mieux <eos>"]

x_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(np.hstack([i.split() for i in x])), range(1, 16)))
y_dict = dict(zip(np.unique(np.hstack([i.split() for i in y])), range(1, 18)))

MAX_LEN_X = 5
MAX_LEN_Y = 7

encoder_input = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_X), dtype='float32')

for i, j in enumerate(x):
    for k, l in enumerate(j.split()):
        encoder_input[i, k] = x_dict[l]

decoder_input = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_Y), dtype='float32')
decoder_output = np.zeros((4, MAX_LEN_Y, len(y_dict)+1), dtype='float32')

for i, j in enumerate(y):
    for k, l in enumerate(j.split()):
        decoder_input[i, k] = y_dict[l]
        if k > 0:
            decoder_output[i, k - 1, y_dict[l]] = 1.

latent_dim = 30
INPUT_VOCAB = len(x_dict) + 1
TARGET_VOCAB = len(y_dict) + 1

print(MAX_LEN_X, MAX_LEN_Y)
# Encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN_X,))
encoder_emb =  Embedding(INPUT_VOCAB, latent_dim, mask_zero=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_lstm(encoder_emb)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

# Decoder
decoder_inputs  = Input(shape=(MAX_LEN_Y,))
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(TARGET_VOCAB, latent_dim, mask_zero=True)
decoder_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(decoder_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_dense = Dense(TARGET_VOCAB, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you. You've mentioned that my vocabulary starts at 1. We have to initialize vocab from 1 isn't it if we initialize from 0 then I'm using mask_zero=True wouldn't this just ignore the vocabulary 0 if that's the case. Also can I know what are these two variables (enc_timesteps  dec_timesteps) you haven't used them.

Comment: I was following the implementation from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py) and then haven't used + 1 for input and target vocab so that's why I didn't used them. Can you check once. I feel like my implementation is wrong.

Comment: @user_12 About `enc_timesteps` and `dec_timesteps`, just ignore them. I didn't realize that you had `MAX_LEN` defined. I'm not very clear about your first question though. Will have a look at the implementation.

Comment: @user_12 In that implementation, they are not using an `Embedding` layer. So this is not an issue for that implementation.

Comment: Thank you for helping out. This above code was just a sample and your fix helped with the sample code but in my original code and when I did like you've mentioned I'm received an another error. Is there a way I can contact you and send me my code. So you can take a look. I'm stuck with it from past one week. I'd really appreciate it if you just take a look at it. It's a seq2seq model with words.

Comment: If you can share a link to your code by uploading it to Github, I can have a look.

Comment: this is the [repo](https://github.com/John-8704/code/blob/master/machine-translation.ipynb) and data is in csv format (30mb) but converted to zip format.

Comment: I'll have a look this week. :)

Comment: I was able to fix the issue above. It was a mistake from my part. Also while looking for attention implementation I came across your code on github [link](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/layers/attention.py) and I was wondering sir how can I make it work with LSTM? Because lstm returns two states right rather than 1? cell state and hidden state? In my project I have Bi-directional lstm and I really want to use attention from your code but couldn't figure out what changes I need to make. If it's possible can you provide some help. I'll write the code for it.

Comment: @user_12 Glad you were able to fix the code. I was hoping to get to this today or tomorrow (had a very busy week). I see you found the link to the AttentionLayer. :) I see your point about LSTM returning two states. Tbh, I don't think I thought of it. I'll have a look into that and let you know if any changes are needed.

Comment: :) thanks for everything. I spent all week trying to fix issue related to encoder and decoder setup and was finally able to train the model. The issue i build my inference setup based on tutorials I've found online. I don't know if it's correct or wrong because the predictions that I've been getting is worse. Even on train dataset. Because I got low loss on train shouldn't it be performing better on train. I think my inference/prediction setup is wrong. If you don't mind can you just take a look once. See if everything's good. I have to give presentation on this few days from now.

Comment: I've updated my code at github link [here](https://github.com/John-8704/code/blob/master/seq2seq-words.ipynb) with everything I've done so far. Please check once when you get some free time if there's something wrong with my encoding or decoding or inference setup.